# How to change property requirement dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've a widget, let's call it `MyText`. It has 2 optional props, `x` and `y`. I want to make `x` mandatory if `y` is defined in the props, and vice versa.

Here is **MyText**

```
interface Props {
  x?: number,
  y?: number,
}

class MyText extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>X is : {this.props.x}</Text>
        <Text>Y is : {this.props.y}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and when i call this, I want to output like this

```
 <MyText x={1} /> // Error: Should say missing y
 <MyText y={4} /> // Error: Should say missing x
 <MyText x={1} y={4}/> // No error
 <MyText/> // No error
```

Is it possible using `TypeScript` ?

**Current solution:**

Using single object to store `x` and `y`, and make it optional.

```
interface XY{
  x : number,
  y : number
}

interface Props {
  xy?: XY,
}

class MyText extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>X is : {this.props.xy.x}</Text>
        <Text>Y is : {this.props.xy.y}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and call it like this

```
<MyText xy={{x:1,y:2}} />
```

I want to know if there's any better method than this, like built-in keywords or other technique to make one property depend on another.

Answer (score 3):

A naïve approach is to specify that `Props` is a union type between an interafec with the mandatory properties and an empty one `{ x: number; y : number } | {}`. The problem with this is that the check for extra properties does not work exactly as expected:

```
let p : { x: number; y : number } | {} = { x: 0 } // Compiler says ok, even though the object has more properties then `{}` and does not satisfy  { x: number; y : number }
```

To get around this, we can use a union where the first member has both `x` and `y` mandatory, and the second member of the union has both properties as optional and of a type that is both rarely used for properties and hard to specify as a literal. The best candidate for this would be `never` :

```
let p1 : { x: number; y : number } | { x?: never; y?: never } = { x: 0, y: 0 } // ok 
let p2 : { x: number; y : number } | { x?: never; y?: never } = { x: 0 }  // invalid
let p3 : { x: number; y : number } | { x?: never; y?: never } = { }  // ok
```

Applying this to your case we get:

```
type Props = {
    x: number,
    y: number,
} | {
    x?: never,
    y?: never,
}

class MyText extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

let s1 = <MyText x={1} /> // Error: Says x is not assignable to never, not ideal but you get used to it
let s2 =  <MyText y={4} /> // Error: Says y is not assignable to y
let s3 =  <MyText x={1} y={4}/> // No error
let s4 =  <MyText/> // No error
```

A way of getting a friendlier error message, would be to use a string literal type with a more friendly message. This does open up the risk that someone will specify the value of the error message, which would make the compiler happy, but hopefully your team members will figure out that `x = 'ERROR: y is missing, you must specify y'` does not make much sense:

```
type Props = {
    x: number,
    y: number,
} | {
    x?: 'ERROR: y is missing, you must specify y',
    y?: 'ERROR: x is missing, you must specify x',
}

let s1 = <MyText x={1} /> // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '"ERROR: y is missing, you must specify y" | undefined'.
let s2 =  <MyText y={4} /> // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '"ERROR: x is missing, you must specify x" | undefined'
let sSilly =  <MyText y='ERROR: x is missing, you must specify x' /> // valid but ilogical enough to not worry about it
let s3 =  <MyText x={1} y={4}/> // No error
let s4 =  <MyText/> // No error
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Titian :)

Comment: @theapache64 added a version with slightly friendlier errors, hope it helps, god luck :)

Comment: thank you :), What do you think about the current solution i specified in the question ? Does it have any performance issue, as the `xy` is passed in `render` method ?

Comment: @theapache64 I wouldn't worry much about it's performance, seems like a decent solution as well :)